# Sending a boolean array across the network

Tags: c++, networking, websocket, cocos2d-x

I am trying to send a two-dimensional boolean array using websocket on C++.
There is a `"data"` struct in websocket and it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Data structure for message
 */
struct Data
{
    Data():bytes(nullptr), len(0), issued(0), isBinary(false){}
    char* bytes;
    ssize_t len, issued;
    bool isBinary;
};
```

Here, I want to send the following packet using the structure above.

```
bool[12][19] info;
```

Threre are 228 boolean value in this array and I was thinking about copying whole information to the char array, which is `bytes` in data.
This will result 228 char values.

I think I could do this, but I feel that it is not so efficient.
Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use bit. But you should maintain the indexing like hash. So an byte could present 8 bit boolean. For your case, probably your need char[228/8 +1] totally.

Comment: Wait, could you give me an example? I am still confused since I have to use a char array to send that info.

Comment: Did you mean by char[228/8+1]?

Comment: Yes, just like the implement of  std::vector<bool>

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a bitmap instead. Given that you know the dimensions of your 2d array, it is easy to find the length of the corresponding single dimensional array. A `char` represents 8 bits of storage on most c++ implementations (certainly all that are supported by cocos2d-x).

Something like this demonstrates the basic idea:

```
#include <assert.h>
static const size_t char_bits = 8;
static const size_t serializedSize = (12*19+(char_bits-1))/(char_bits);

class ByteArraySerialize
{
protected:

void serialize(char* dst, bool src[12][19]){
  for(int x=0; x<12; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<19; y++){
      bool b = src[x][y];
      int i=x*19+y;
      assert(i < serializedSize*char_bits);
      int i_char = i / char_bits;
      int i_bit = i % char_bits;
      if(b)
        dst[i_char] |= 1 << i_bit;
      else
        dst[i_char] &= ~(1 << i_bit);
    }
  }
}

void deserialize(bool dst[12][19], const char* src){
  for(int x=0; x<12; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<19; y++){
      int i=x*19+y;
      assert(i < serializedSize*char_bits);
      int i_char = i / char_bits;
      int i_bit = i % char_bits;
      bool b = ((src[i_char] >> i_bit) & 0x01) != 0;
      dst[x][y] = b;
    }
  }
}

public:
ByteArraySerialize(){
  char charbuf[serializedSize];
  bool data_1[12][19] = { 0 };
  bool data_2[12][19] = { 0 };
  for(int x=0; x<12; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<19; y++)
      data_1[x][y] = rand()%1!=0;
  serialize(charbuf,data_1);
  deserialize(data_2, charbuf);

  for(int x=0; x<12; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<19; y++)
      assert(data_1[x][y] == data_2[x][y]);
}
};

ByteArraySerialize testByteArray;
```